# Does SORBS (DNSBL) contains domain names?

Tags: dns, spam-prevention, email-filter, mail-server

I’m researching [SORBS](http://www.sorbs.net/) (Spam and Open Relay Blocking System) and its function in DNS-based Blackhole Lists (DNSBLs).

My question is straightforward: Is SORBS limited to storing only IP addresses, or does it also catalog other types of data, such as domain names or URLs?

Comment: It certainly catalogs domain names - it says as much in its documentation.  I don't believe it catalogs URLS as if I understand correctly it uses DNS mechanisms for tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They catalog **domain names and IP addresses**, and may additionally group by their ASN and country. For example, here's their list of top 20 spamming IPs and domains:

http://www.sorbs.net/home/stats.shtml

---

Paraphrased from their Submissions page here: http://www.sorbs.net/listing/submission.shtml

> ### What can be submitted to SORBS...?
>
> Submissions to SORBS can be made for the following:
>
> - The Dynamic User/Host List (DUHL): This is a IP based list
> - The Bad DNS Config List: This is a domain based list
> - The No e-mail from this domain list: This is a domain based list

It only relates to email server addresses, so URLs are not involved. Take a look at their [FAQ](http://www.us.sorbs.net/information/faq/) and their [About Listings](http://www.us.sorbs.net/listing/aboutlistings.shtml) pages to learn about how and why they're used

Comment: Could you provide me with an example of a real domain name that is listed in baddns or nomail? I couldn't find any, and it's really important for my research.

Comment: @D.Bence an example of what? Check their usage page for how to check against them or configure common applications to use it: http://www.us.sorbs.net/general/using.shtml . It's free to query the lists from any computer like `nslookup 133.183.29.103.dnsbl.sorbs.net` for example. At the bottom, they say you may request a local copy of the SORBS data by using the transfer request page. If you just want a single example, you should email them and ask for a sample domain from the nomail list to query.