# Looking for an example of a domain that is blocklisted in SORBS?

Tags: email, dns, blacklist

Could someone show me an example of a domain that is blocklisted in [SORBS](http://www.sorbs.net/) (Spam and Open Relay Blocking System)?

There are two zones, nomail and baddns, which contain domain names, but I can’t find one.

Comment: Why was this question closed but [this other question about SORBS](https://superuser.com/q/1824509/167207) left alone?

Comment: My first question was about the existence of such a list, but now I want to find a specific domain within that list.

Comment: @D.Bence - Which isn’t of scope. Your other question could be answered and something could be quoted. In the case of this question you just want an example of a domain that’s been blocked.

Comment: I understand, thanks!